# how to flip Image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I recently learned how to rotate a BitmapImage using the 'TransformedBitmap' and 'RotateTransformed' classes. Now I am able to perform clockwise rotations on my images. But how do I FLIP an image? I can't find the class(es) to perform horizontal and vertical flips of a BitmapImage. Please help me figure out how to do it. For instance, if my image was a drawing that looked like a 'd', then a vertical flip would result in something like a 'q', and a horizontal flip would result in something like a 'b'.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

[Use a ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348048.aspx) with a ScaleX of -1 for horizontal and ScaleY of -1 for vertical flipping, applied to the image's `RenderTransform`  property. Using `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` on the image makes sure your image gets flipped around its center, so you won't have to apply an additional TranslateTransform to move it into place:

```
<Image Source="a.jpg" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

for horizontal flipping and

```
<Image Source="a.jpg" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

for vertical.

If you want to do it in code-behind, in C# it should look something like this:

```
img.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5);
ScaleTransform flipTrans = new ScaleTransform();
flipTrans.ScaleX = -1;
//flipTrans.ScaleY = -1;
img.RenderTransform = flipTrans;
```

Comment: How can i Flip a `BitmapFrame` ?

Answer (score 9):

To give your flip a little more "depth" so that is looks more like a true flip you probably want to do a skew transform with a smaller scale transform.

You would want to skew the object about 20 degrees to make it look as if it is flipping in 3D. This is a poor mans 3D flip. You can accomplish a true 3D flip in WPF but that takes a bit more work.

This will give you the animation that looks cleaner, then you can toggle visibility on two different panels to give the impression of a front and a backside to your element.

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="1" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.09" Value="0.3" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.12" Value="0.6" />                              
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.15" Value="0.8" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.18" Value="1" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="1" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.09" Value="0.9" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.18" Value="1" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleY)">
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.06" Value="-10" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.09" Value="-20" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1" Value="20" />
  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.18" Value="0" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick trick for horizontal (only) flipping btw is to set FlowDirection property to FlowDirection.RightToLeft. If the component is a container though, some children of it may interpret the property differently (custom logic)

Comment: This just saved me, since it flips the image without moving it.

Comment: btw, probably you were missing RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" if it was moving if you tried the ScaleTransform with -1 for x-scale. However it is indeed much more straightforward to read in the code (or put in XAML) too with the FlowDirection, rather than the transforms approach

Answer (score 5):

```
<Image x:Name="SampleImage"  Margin="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="0" AngleX="0"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
```

Create an image component like this. And when its source is set, the image will flip from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting 3d flippable usercontrol: http://flipcontrol.codeplex.com/releases/view/22358

In your case you will have to display on both sides the same image.

Comment: for flipping container control check out http://clipflair.codeplex.com, under the Client\ZUI folder the FlipPanel project

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) with negative `ScaleX`/`ScaleY`:

```
  <TextBlock Text="P">
   <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="-1" />
   </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
  </TextBlock>
```